# help with winsys module

Tags: python, windows, event-log

i am trying to use the WinSys module to get the event logs of my system(windows). But i dont know why the following code doesnt run:

```
from winsys import event_logs
print len (event_logs.event_log ("Application"))
```

or

```
for logs in event_logs.event_logs(computer='.'):
    print logs
```

these yield errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q:\8th sem\python\untitled1.py", line 10, in <module>
    event_logs.event_log("Application")
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\winsys\event_logs.py", line 376, in event_log
    return EventLog (computer, log_name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\winsys\event_logs.py", line 119, in __init__
    key = registry.registry (self.REG_ROOT % self.computer).get_key (self.name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\winsys\registry.py", line 503, in registry
    return Registry.from_string (root, access=access, accept_value=accept_value)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\winsys\registry.py", line 485, in from_string
    hKey, moniker, value = cls._from_string (string, access, accept_value)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\winsys\registry.py", line 469, in _from_string
    hRoot = wrapped (win32api.RegConnectRegistry, computer, root)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\winsys\exc.py", line 44, in _wrapped
    raise exception (errno, errctx, errmsg)
winsys.registry.x_registry: (53, 'RegConnectRegistry', 'The network path was not found.')
```

Is there anything im missing?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from RegConnectRegistry documentation [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__RegConnectRegistry_meth.html):

> **computerName : string**
>   The name of the remote computer, of the form \\computername. If **None**, the local
>   computer is used.

Thus the default computer name value "." cannot be used in this function. It seems like there is bug in Winsys version you are using. In my local Winsys version 0.5.2 (taken from PYPI) the problem seems to be corrected.

You can work around the issue by using the following code:

```
import win32api
from winsys import event_logs
moniker = "\\\\%s\\Application" % win32api.GetComputerName()
print len(event_logs.event_log(moniker))
```

Comment: i installed the winsys 0.5.2 version and used the above code but it still doesnt work

Comment: 'code' Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q:\8th sem\python\untitled1.py", line 4, in <module>
    print len(event_logs.event_log(moniker))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\winsys\event_logs.py", line 385, in event_log
    return EventLog (computer or ".", log_name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\winsys\event_logs.py", line 123, in __init__
    core._WinSysObject.__init__ (self)
AttributeError: class _WinSysObject has no attribute '__init__''code'

Comment: This issue is fixed in Winsys SVN trunk, but you can fix it yourself by opening C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\winsys\core.py file and change line 13 to: `class _WinSysObject(object):`